# Investigating the "Leesburg split" rainfall anomaly

Tags: rainfall, mapping, thunderstorm, radar, united-states

I've spent some time in the Leesburg, Virginia (USA) area and I've noticed that whenever a line of thunderstorms approaches the area, it frequently splits and goes around a particular spot just southeast of Leesburg, leaving it almost completely dry.  The locals even have a name for it.  They call it the "Leesburg split".

I've been trying to investigate this and see objective confirmation that this is a real thing, perhaps with a high-resolution rainfall map of the area or a map of compounded/cumulative radar activity.  But I just can't seem to find the right tool.  Perhaps I don't know how to google for meteorological tools.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

**I would just like to see a cumulative rainfall map of the area.**

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of the "Leesburg split" by googling. I do notice, however, that a massive natural-gas power plant, the [Potomac Energy Center](https://ghgdata.epa.gov/ghgp/service/facilityDetail/2020?id=1012160&ds=E&et=&popup=true), is just southeast of Leesburg.  It dumps massive amounts of heat and CO2 into the atmosphere.

Comment: Google yields me at least two Facebook posts with radar images: https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=809125377249221&id=100044552974374 & https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=827582968736795&id=100044552974374

Comment: The National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration undertakes weather observations for the US, including [rain radar](https://www.nws.noaa.gov/radar_tab.php) results.

Comment: Thanks, @Fred.  I have not had good luck getting that site to cooperate.  Do you know how to use it to generate high-resolution cumulative rainfall maps of the area?